# How to remove elements from externally loaded content within colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Trying to remove google maps from externally loaded content within colorbox but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".link").colorbox({
onComplete: function() {
$("#map").remove();
}
});
});
```

Comment: It might be in an iframe.  Try $('iframe', this).remove();

Comment: sorry "$('iframe', this).remove();" not working